# printing a char pointer ... what happens?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

i'm new to C and i've got a question about char pointers and what it will print . take a look :

```
int main()
{
char *p1="ABCD";
p1="EFG";
printf ("%s",p1);
return 0;
}
```

it will print EFG

and now :

```
int main()
{
char *p1="ABCD";
//p1="EFG";
printf ("%s",p1);
return 0;
}
```

and it will give you ABCD

The point that I don't get is what exactly `*p1` is ?
Is it a number of an address that contains a `char` value ?
Is it a `char` ?
what is in `*p1` right now ? Why is it `const` ?

Comment: `p1` is a pointer to the first character in a string.  That's all.

Comment: it's char, and const even it's not defined to be so, and the first char of the string you give.

Comment: Elaborating on what @OliverCharlesworth said: When C was new, people learning it were used to Assembler and understood intuitively that a pointer was just a variable that contained the address of something. On a word machine, a char* could be the address of a word and a character offset. But the notion pointer has evolved as languages evolve. In C++, pointers have been generalized to _iterators_, which can be themselves complex objects. It is not useful to think in terms of what a pointer _really_ is, under the hood. A pointer points to something. It doesn't matter how.

Comment: that's not cool. live in C means live with pointers. it's essential to know what exactly pointer is, without any bias. no blackbox works in c.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

```
EXAMPLE 8 The declaration

  char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
  defines ‘‘plain’’ char array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals.

This declaration is identical to

  char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
  t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration

  char *p = "abc";

defines p with type ‘‘pointer to char’’ and initializes it to point to an object
with type ‘‘array of char’’ with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a
character string literal. If an attempt is made to use p to modify the contents
of the array, the behavior is undefined.
```

In other words:

1) `char *p1;` declares a variable (p1) that is a pointer.  The pointer, p1 can be changed.

2) `char *p1 = "ABCD";` declares p1 (same as "1") and also initializes the data it points to (initializes it to the read-only, 5-lelement character array "ABCD\0").

So you can change the address "p1" points to (you can make it point to "EFG", assign it to NULL, etc. etc).  But you *CANNOT* safely change the data itself.  You'll probably get an "access violation" if you try to overwrite "ABCD".  The exact behavior is "undefined" - *ANYTHING* can happen.

3) `char p2[] = "ABCD";` declares a variable (p2) that is an array.  It allocates 5 characters, and initializes the data to "ABCD\0".

The array is read-write (you can change the data in the array), but the variable "p2" cannot be changed (you cannot change p2 to point to a different address - because it's not a pointer).

4) So what's the "difference" between a char *pointer and a char array[]?  Here is a good discussion:

http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: N1124 is a draft of the C99 standard. [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is a more current C99 draft; it includes all three Technical Corrigenda. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the latest publicly available draft of the 2011 ISO C standard.

Comment: The text I quoted is exactly the same in both versions: I just happened to find a link to the draft first.  I updated the citation to N1256.  A list of all related C/ISO documentation is here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#9899. Frankly, I'd recommend just reading [K&R](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628).

Comment: K&R is excellent for some purposes, but (a) it's not intended as a rigorous definition of the language (most of it is more of a tutorial), and (b) the second edition "K&R2" refers to the 1990 version of the language.  There have been two updated standards since then, in 1999 and 2011. But yes, K&R is almost certainly better than the ISO standard for *learning* the language.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    char *p1="ABCD";
    p1="EFG";
    printf ("%s",p1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is missing the required `#include <stdio.>`. Without it, your compiler might let you get away with calling `printf`, but it's not guaranteed to work. And a minor point: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

There's actually quite a lot going on in this program, and some of it is rather subtle.

```
char *p1 = "ABCD";
```

`"ABCD"` is a *string literal*. It specifies an anonymous array object of type `char[5]` (4 for the characters you specified plus 1 for the `'\0'` null character that marks the end of the string). That object has *static storage duration*, which means that it exists during the entire execution of your program (unlike a local variable, for example, which ceases to exist when it goes out of scope (that's a slight oversimplification)).

An array expression is, in most contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. So `p1` is initialized to point to the character `'A'`, the first character of that anonymous array object.

`p1` *should* be defined as `const char *p1 = ...`. It's not actually required, but it will help the compiler catch any attempt to modify the array object. (The object is not `const`, but modifying it has undefined behavior.)

```
p1 = "EFG";
```

Now the value stored in `p1` is clobbered and replaced by a new pointer value, this time pointing to the `'E'` of the string literal `"EFG"`. (So there was no point in initializing it, but that's ok.)

```
printf("%s", p1);
```

Here we pass the value of `p1` (a pointer value) to the `printf` function.

At this point, the value of `*p1` is `'E'`, and is of type `char`. But `printf` is able to print the entire string `"EFG"`. It uses *pointer arithmetic* to do so. Somewhere in the implementation of `printf`, there's a loop that takes the pointer value that was passed in, dereferences it to obtain the character value to be printed, and then increments the pointer so it points to the next character of the string (`'F'`). This loop continues until it reaches the `'\0'` null character that marks the end of the string; that null character is not printed.

Since arrays are in a sense "second-class citizens" in C, most operations on array objects are done this way, using pointers to the array elements to traverse the array. (You can also use indexing notation `arr[i]`, which does essentially the same thing.) `printf` doesn't have direct access to the array object itself; it relies on the pointer (to its first element) to determine where the array is in memory, and on the `'\0'` terminator to determine where the string ends.

The second program is the same, except that `p1` is not reassigned, so the string `"ABCD"` is printed.

The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) does a very good job of explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't get is what exactly `*p1` is ?
>   Is it a number of an address that contains a char value ? Is it a char ?

If you are talking about `*p1` in the declaration

```
char *p1 = "ABCD";
```

then `*` indicates that `p1` is a pointer to `char` (in fact `const char` in this case). `p1` just points to the first character of the string literal `ABCD`.

If you are asking about `*p1` as in

```
printf("%c", *p1);
```

then `*` here is an indirection operator and `*p1` means the value of the character `p1` points to which is `A`. `*p1` is equivalent to `p1[0]`.
The statement

```
 p1 = "DEF";
```

let `p1` point to first character of the string literal `DEF`.

> Why is it `const` ?

String literals are stored in *read-only* section of memory.

```
char *p1 = "ABCD";
```

is equivalent to

```
char const *p1 = "ABCD";
```

This means that you can't modify a string literal.

```
*p1 = 'a'; // WRONG. Invokes undefined behavior.
```

Answer (score 1):

`p1` is a `char` pointer which holds the *base address* or *starting address* or *the address of the first element* of the *string* *assigned* to it using `=` operator.

In your first code, you've assigned the base address of "ABCD" to it, later the base address of "EFG" [which overwrites the previous value] and finally printing it. So, the latest value ["EFG"] is printed.

In second case, you're assigning the base address of "ABCD" and printing it. So it prints `ABCD`.
Maybe worthy to mention, the `%s` format specifier in `printf()` expects the starting *address* of a null-terminated string, which is here, pointed by `p1`.

As per the `const` part, the *value* of the *string* pointed by `p1` is constant in this case, as string literals are usually stored in read-only memory locations. Means, altering the values, `p[1] = 's'` is not allowed. However, the pointer `p1` is not `const`, so it can be re-assigned to a new value `p1="EFG";` rightly.

Comment: how does it answer the question.?

Comment: @Madan  For example as for me then I have not understood the question.:)

Comment: Thanks but what do i have assigned the address "ABCD" to ?! is it the address of sth that the programmer doesn't know ?!

Comment: @Madan how does is not? Please let me know what else is reqd.

Comment: @Behrus58 the _base address_ of "ABCD" string is assigned to `p1`.

Comment: Thanks so why do the stacks overflow when i write : printf ("%s",*p1);  ?! shouldn't it just print "A" ?!

Comment: @Behrus58 you should write `printf ("%s",p1);` The `%s` specifies a string pointer: you have given the first char of the string.

Comment: @Behrus58 notice the mention of `null-terminated` terminology. that's the sign of end-of-string, i.e. upto that part printf() will print.

Comment: @Weather Vane  yes you are right thanks . so i wrote printf ("%c",*p1);  and it printed "E" but i expected to see "A" based on the answers ...

Comment: @Behrus58 i hope you're referring to case 1. then it;s correct, because the base address of "ABCD" is overwritten by the base address of "EFG" now [by `p1="EFG";`], and the first character is indeed `E`.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh So *p1 is always the [0] block of it's address , and as long as you can change the address , you can change *p1[0] ... am i right ?

Comment: @Behrus58 yes, in _this_ case, you're right. also check the update in my answer. I expanded it a bit.

Comment: @Behrus58 *"you can change `*p1[0]`"* ... almost right, but `*p1[0]`would be an array of pointers. To change the first element of the string (apart from the fact that you should not change a string literal) you change `*p1` or `p1[0]`. To change the second element of the string you change `*(p1+1)` or `p1[1]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Right you are, I overlooked. In this case, its either `p1[0]` or `*p1` for the first element.

Answer (score 1):

`p1` is a char pointer that holds the address of where the compiler put "ABCD" in memory.  The address is of the first character in the array.

When you have `char *p1 = "ABCD";` you are just assigning the value of the address held in `p1`.
When you reassign `p1 = "EFG";` you are reassigning the pointer to hold a new address (where "EFG" is)

`printf ("%s",p1);`  prints the contents of memory in the location `p1` points to.

Answer (score 1):

Initially p1 is declared as a char pointer and points to "ABCD" (base address of "ABCD").

Later the pointer points to "EFG" (contains the base address of "EFG")

```
+----+      +---+
|ABCD|      |EFG|
+----+      +---+
 1000        2000

char *p1="ABCD";
         +----+
before   |1000|
         +----+
          p1
p1="EFG";
After    +----+
         |2000|
         +----+
          p1
```

Comment: Isn't it vice versa  :D ?!

Answer (score 0):

> The point that i don't get is what exactly *p1 is ! is it a number of an address that contains a char value ? is it a char ?  what is in *p1 right now ?

The type of `*p1` is `char`. Its value is the character `'A'`.

> why is it `const` ?

String literals, like `"ABCD"`, are placed in read only memory. Modifying them through `p` is cause for undefined behavior. That's why `*p1` is read only, i.e. it's a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> The point that i don't get is what exactly *p1 is !  is it a number of an address that contains a char value ? is it a char ? what is in *p1 right now ?

The value of `*p1` is `p1[0]`, that is a `char` of value `'E'` in your first program and of value `'A'` in your second program.

> why is it const ?

It is not `const` in C (it is in in C++), but string literals are specified to be non-modifiable in C which means an attempt to modify `*p1` invokes undefined behavior.